# Python - Simple expression to find greatest odd number below n

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers

As the title already states I'm searching for a simple expression to find the greatest odd number below some `n`:

I want to inline this code into an arithmetic expression and don't want to use the ternary operator. Is there an arithmetic way to find this odd number?

Comment: You are not using statements here, but a trinary operator.

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you. I'll edit the post.

Comment: This is an example of the number odd number greater than or equal to without a conditional - not sure if this is helpful
(testNumber >> 1 << 1) | 1

Comment: Why don't you want to use the ternary operator? The Python conditional expression is quite efficient.

Comment: @PM2Ring I want to use it inside a `range` and I think that it just look not clean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a purely arithmetic solution:

```
def greatest_odd_number_below(n): return (n//2)*2 - 1
```

**EDIT 1**: For floating point inputs:

```
# python 2 solution
from math import ceil
def greatest_odd_number_below_floats(n): return (int(ceil(n))//2)*2 - 1
```

**EDIT 2**: As @PM 2Ring pointed out in the comments, `math.ceil` returns an `int` in python 3, so you can remove the additional casting to `int`.

```
# python 3 solution
from math import ceil
def greatest_odd_number_below_floats(n): return (ceil(n)//2)*2 - 1
```

Comment: So 9 will be mapped to 7?

Comment: Yes, 7 is the greatest odd number less than 9.

Comment: What do people downvote this answer? It is readable and does everything I asked for.

Comment: A lambda is supposed to be an anonymous function, please don't use `lambda` to create a named function.

Comment: You could also just do `def greatest_odd_number_below(n):
  return n//2 * 2 - 1`

Comment: Do you have an idea how to handle floating point numbers this way?

Comment: @RoadRunner Indeed, except the parentheses aren't needed.

Comment: @RoadRunner Do you have an idea how to handle floating point numbers this way? For example `greatest_odd_number_below(3.6)` should return `3`.

Comment: This won't support floating point inputs, since on input `3.6` it'll return `1`.

Comment: You can use `math.ceil` to get the desired output for floating point numbers. I have made an edit to the post.

Comment: FWIW, in Python 3 `math.ceil` returns an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

How about this where testNumber is your variable

```
(testNumber - 1 >> 1 << 1) | 1 # LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO

(testNumber - 2 >> 1 << 1) | 1 # LESS THAN
```

Comment: I think you want `(testNumber - 2 >> 1 << 1 | 1)`?

Comment: I assume from all the `int` calls in the OP's code that the arg may not necessarily be an `int`. Of course, I may be totally wrong. ;)

Comment: I upvoted this answer but one could argue that the bitwise OR (`|`) is a conditional

Comment: @pault No, it's not a conditional, `|` is the bitwise OR operation. It's implemented purely via arithmetic, it doesn't use conditional branching.

Comment: Okay- you are right, there is no branching. I concede this point. This is an excellent solution.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, it does exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: @RoadRunner What's wrong with my solution? It also does what the OP wants.

Comment: Bitwise operations are more efficient.

Comment: But you _do_ need to change it to `(testNumber - 2 >> 1 << 1) | 1` because the OP wants the largest odd number that's strictly smaller than `testNumber`.

Comment: @pault your solution is also excellent, I didn't have a closer look at it. I would upvote both answers, but I'm out of them for the day :(.

Comment: @PM2Ring Exactly.

Comment: True, bitwise ops are more efficient, but Python arithmetic isn't particularly fast anyway. `n // 2 * 2 - 1` is pretty basic, and it has one less operator than your version. Also, bitwise ops are less readable for many people than the more common arithmetic ops are.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to handle floating point numbers this way? For example `greatest_odd_number_below(3.6)`
 should return `3`?

Comment: @user9115052 If you change it to `(ceil(testNumber) - 2 >> 1 << 1) | 1` it will handle floats.

Comment: i cannot get this to work in the fiddle unfortunately and don't have an IDE handy, but i think the point is rather than using 2 hard-coded, to use 1 + int(testnumber)-floor(testnumber)...that will give you a 1 if it's an integer, otherwise a 2...and that should work in theory

Comment: I prefer my version. ;) At least, you should avoid calling `int(testNumber)` twice. Also, `math.floor` returns an `int` in Python 3, so you don't need to wrap it in a call to the `int` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
n - n%2 - 1
```

Demo:

```
>>> for n in range(10):
        print(n, '->', n - n%2 - 1)

0 -> -1
1 -> -1
2 -> 1
3 -> 1
4 -> 3
5 -> 3
6 -> 5
7 -> 5
8 -> 7
9 -> 7
```

Comment: This is nice as well. Can you come up with a clever method to support floating point values as well? E.g. `greatest_odd_below(3.6) = 3`?

Answer (score 0):

***babygameOver*** is right. There is no such built-in function, so you should implement it by yourself.

Just to put my 2 cents, you can use lambda expressions. Looks pretty simple.

```
>>> odd = lambda n: n-1 if n % 2 == 1 else n - 1
>>> odd(3)
3
>>> odd(744)
743
```

Comment: @RoadRunner It should be `n-1 if n %% 2 == 1 else n - 1`. I'm looking for the greatest odd number _below_ `n`.

Comment: Ok, ok, just missed does author needs odd or even number, why so panic, already changed that

Comment: @user9115052 Still not right, `n-1 if n % 2 == 1 else n - 1`.

Comment: `onething if ... else exactsamething` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score -1):

Without conditional you can't solve the scenario.

but you can do this way  as you have done in yours.

```
def odd(n):
    if n%2==0:
        return n-1
    return n

print(odd(3))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: How do you know that it's not possible without conditional?

Comment: It's a math, the definition says it that the number divisible by 2 is even else odd.

Comment: This doesn't imply that the scenario cannot be solved without using conditional. Check the answer below.

Comment: that is also a condition that you are returning the value if the condition satisfies based on the lambda

Comment: `(n//2)*(2) - 1` isn't a condition, but an arithmetic expression.

Comment: yeah but the lambda is sort of the conditional https://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php . I don't like lambda

Comment: His new answer does not include a lambda.